# Print WPF grid is cropped

Tags: wpf

I found function to print content of Wpf grid but the print is cropped.
Can anybody know why?

the function:

```
private void PrintTest()
        {
            FlowDocument document;
            Window window;
            CreateWindowToPrint(out document, out window);    
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();   
            window.Show();
            IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = document;
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                printDialog.PrintDocument(dps.DocumentPaginator, "test");
            }
        }
```

and:

```
 private void CreateWindowToPrint(out FlowDocument document, out
 Window window)
         {
             document = new FlowDocument {  };
             var test = new PrintedTest() { DataContext = this.DataContext };
             document.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer { Child = test });
             window = new Window {Content = document, Visibility =       System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden };
         }
```

The UserControl PrintedTest contains my grid.

Comment: I am assuming the information in the Window it is not cropped?

Comment: The information in the window is not cropped.but when I printed directly from the window it's also croped

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have much experience with printing in WPF but I thought I would give it a try.
I could reproduce your problem, and I could not solve it so far.
But In my research I have found an alternative, which is more simple to print the Grid:

```
        var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        var result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
        {
            var testControl = new PrintedTest() { DataContext = this.DataContext };
            printDialog.PrintVisual(testControl, "My WPF printing a DataGrid");
        }
```

Instead of sending the PrintTest you could actually just send directly the grid.